# .validate rule: check jquery var

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So, i'm trying to take a jQuery var and use it as a rule for the .validate plugin.
The var comes from a function that runs a function and give 1 for true and 0 for false, the problem is that i can't make the rule return true or false for the validate function. The code reads:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cpfc", function(){
    if (($(CPF.valida($(cpf).val())).size()) === '1' )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

`$(CPF.valida($(cpf).val())).size()` = `1` or `0`, depends on the function check, I ran this function on the console and it's returning the correct values.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the element/value of `cpf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semi-colon between the `if` and `else` statement which will be causing a syntax error. Also note that `size()` (aside from being deprecated) returns an integer, so your current code will always return `false` as you compare it to a string. It's now recommended to use the `length` property instead:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cpfc", function(){
    if ($(CPF.valida($(cpf).val())).length === 1) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

This can be further reduced to just

```
$.validator.addMethod("cpfc", function(){
    return $(CPF.valida($(cpf).val())).length === 1;
});
```

You should also ensure that the `CPF` object and `cpf` variable are in scope and hold the values you expect when called from within the validator method.

Comment: I worked!! Thank you so much, i was struggling over this one! ^^ Cheers!